# Is this sentence grammaritcally correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis

There are published procedures.

Should I say "spreaded"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. we have some issues with your Q: Basically you are asking for proof-reading, which we don't do here. Also, it is unclear what "spreaded" has to do with it.

Comment: @Cascabel I wouldn't entirely rule out "speaded". The OED has two examples of its adjectival use from the last half-century: - *1967   Asian Folklore Stud. 26 134   Sitting or standing in a circle, the woman folk with spreaded locks and careless dress, sing these songs.
2001   Epidemiology & Infection 127 498/1   A slow rise was noted, with more spreaded curve, reaching the maximum value later.*

Comment: You need to correct the misspelling of "grammatically" in the question.

Comment: Hunh...I wasn't ruling it out, but the OP was asking us to make a connection which was not completely clear. I realize now that they were asking if it could substitute for "published".@WS2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"There are published procedures" is correct.

"Spreaded" isn't a word. The past tense of "spread" is the same, "spread". More importantly, "spread" is not used in this way to indicated "distributed". Various correct alternatives might be:

```
"There is widely distributed information on the procedures."

"Details of the procedures are spread throughout the training manual."

"He spread the news of the change in procedures."
```

Comment: Or "disseminated"